# Angular 5 ngx-bootstrap form validation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I'm reading Ari Lerner's `ng-book` on Angular 5.  I'm using `ngx-bootstrap` and `Bootstrap 4`.  Form validation doesn't seem to be working the way Mr. Lerner implements.  I'm not sure if this is a limitation of `ngx-bootstrap`...anyone know?

**edit**
Ok, I removed `ngx-bootstrap` and just loaded up the MaxCDNs for `Bootstrap 4` and I have the same problem.  The error message is not appearing.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from './registration-form/registration-form.component';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup
} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    RegistrationFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**registration-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-form',
  templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent implements OnInit {
  regForm: FormGroup;
  // name: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.regForm = fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.required],
      // 'email': ['', Validators.required],
      // 'password': ['', Validators.required],
      // 'password_confirmation': ['', Validators.required]
    });

    // this.name = this.regForm.controls['name'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(value: string): void{
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

**registration-form.component.html**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <h1>New User</h1>
</div>

<div class='row justify-content-center'>
  <div class='col-6'>
    <form [formGroup]='regForm'
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(regForm.value)"
    [class.error]="!regForm.valid && regForm.touched"
    >
      <div class='form-group'
        [class.error]="!regForm.get('name').valid && regForm.get('name').touched">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' [formControl]="regForm.controls['name']">
        <div *ngIf="regForm.controls['name'].hasError('required')" class="invalid-feedback">Name is required</div>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class='form-control'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class='form-control'>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Confirmation</label>
        <input type="password" class='form-control'>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you give code.

Answer (score 4):

It'll work by adding a `class="was-validated"` to the outer most div as per documentation: [link to bootstrap form validation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#validation). This will initiate the validation on your fields. Also, remember to flag your inputs with `required` and turn of default html validation by passing the form a `novalidate`

Example of working code:

```
<div class="container" class="was-validated">
  <form [formGroup]="regForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitForm(regForm.value)">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label class="col-12 col-form-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control form-control-lg col-12" id="email" [formControl]="regForm.controls['email']"
          required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid email.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <label class="col-12 col-form-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-lg col-12" [formControl]="regForm.controls['password']" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a password.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block col-12">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You could - and probably should, add the `class="was-validated"` programmatically, not hardcode it like i did.

If you have any trouble with this, feel free to comment my post - and i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Props to @ChrisEenberg on this. If you want to have each field be validated as the user types, put the was-validated on the form-group

`<div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'was-validated': (categoryVar.touched || categoryVar.dirty) && !categoryVar.valid }">`